# Sending data from page to another page with a html button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have problem in sending some value from code behind to another page.

I have an input button that's enabled when the check box is true (write with js) now I want a call event for this button so the code behind that will send some value to another page .

This is my html button:

```
<input type="button"   Class="btn btn-primary pull-left" id="del_event" name="del_event" value="confirm"   disabled="disabled">
```

I have 2 values that need be send in the code behind.

How can I send these values to another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use just an `HTML` tag instead of an asp.net button you may use `query string`. Wrap your button inside an `<a>` element. Like this:

```
<a href="a.html?var1=val1&var2=val2"><input type="button" value="click"></a>
```

Comment: thanks.i used asp:linkbutton instead of tag <a>.now i can send my arguments to other page in easy way.

Comment: You can send your data from one page to another via `session`, `query string` or `cookie`. all are possible for a code-behind approach.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session to keep the value in this page behind ,and then get it in anohter page behind.

Comment: How can i response.redirect to page 2  with html button?and if i use tag <a> my button always is enabled